# Connection error 1044 when connecting to a database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a `MySQL` database by using `PHP`. The `PHP` code that I have is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Testing SQL connection...</p>
        <?php
            $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'script');
            if (!$db) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
            echo 'Connected successfully';
            mysqli_close($db);
        ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

And when I run the code to see if it connects successfully, I get the following error message `Could not connect: 1044`. I've saved the script on my local machine and all the details I've entered into the `$db = mysqlli_connect` line are all correct. I've tried looking online for help but I'm struggling to find anything that'll help

Comment: script database is exists ?

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the command line using these credentials?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh The script database does exist

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I've logged into MySQL Workbench with the same credentials, it has worked

Comment: i tries this. it worked on my side..  $db = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', '', 'database_name_you_want_to_connect');
            if (!$db) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());
            }
            echo 'Connected successfully';
            mysqli_close($db);

Comment: @RanjeetSingh When I've tried that, it came back with `Could not connect: 1045`

Comment: i think may be it's your database not exists(As you say 'script' db is not exists). That's why it is denied to access. (check your username, password, database is valid to which you are trying to connect)

Comment: @RanjeetSingh the `script` database does exist. As I have it open along side the PHP script and it still isn't working.

Comment: Please check your credentials. your credentials are not correct to connect to database(YOU ARE TRYING TO CONNECT TO DATABASE THAT WAS NOT EXISTS).

Comment: @RanjeetSingh The credentials are the exactly the same that I've put into the PHP script and as I log into MySQL Workbench. And the database does exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108697/discussion-between-ranjeet-singh-and-smitthy).

Answer (score 1):

> Error: 1044 SQLSTATE: 42000 (ER_DBACCESS_DENIED_ERROR)
>
> Message: Access denied for user '%s'@'%s' to database '%s'

You will want to double-check that the correct username and password are being passed. I would advise echo'ing them for debug purposes.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that those are the correct username and password that I use for MySQL Workbench, as I've logged into it multiple times throughout the day :)